# How can an Azure DevOps task use the Output of a previous Azure DevOps task

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

When executing a DevOps Release Pipeline:

While currently executing Task 2, I would like to reference the Output from Task 1.  (Task 1 retrieves json from a REST api call.)

They are both in the same Agentless Job (they are both REST api calls). basically i'm trying to "chain" them together and/or pass the json output from Task 1 to Task 2

I have seen documentation on variables, but I am not sure if I can set variables via Task 1's output, or even better if there was something built-in, like ${PreviousStep.Output}

Is this even possible?

Comment: which task is task 1?

Comment: it is a task that calls a REST api

Comment: Are your tasks in the same job?

Comment: Yes they are, they are both in the same Agentless Job (they are both REST api calls).  basically trying to "chain" them together and/or pass the json output from Task 1 to Task 2

Comment: Hi @JBoothUA, How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: hello thanks for your help, i'm messing around with powershell output formatting and things now but i can confirm that powershell is a valid solution for chaining API calls, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could create a temporary file in pipeline and save the response body to the file, then read the file in the next power shell.

In my sample, I get release pipeline definition in the first power shell task and save the output to the temporary file, then read it in the next power shell task.

Sample pipeline definition

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'


steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      New-Item $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\test1.txt
      $outfile = "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\test1.txt"
      Write-Host $outfile
      $url = "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{Org name}/{Project name}/_apis/release/definitions/{Definition ID}?api-version=6.0-preview.4"
      Write-Host "URL: $url"
      $connectionToken="{PAT}"
      $base64AuthInfo= [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($connectionToken)"))
      $pipelineInfo = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{authorization = "Basic $base64AuthInfo"} -Method Get
      $pipelineInfo | Out-File -FilePath $outfile
      
      

      

- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      $json = Get-Content -Path $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\test1.txt
      Write-Host $json
```

Result:

[image]